# Request body is blank through cURL request in golang

Tags: json, api, rest, go, curl

I am sending a PUT request using cURL which has request body in json form but while parsing that request.body. it is giving error **unexpected end of JSON input**

Here is my cURL

> curl --location --request PUT 'something.com/something/test/1' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"name": "test-update"}'

Here is code snippet from my go code

```
func PutHandler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {

    log.Debugf(" test log request.RequestURI is %s request.Body %+v, request.Method %s", request.RequestURI, request.Body, request.Method)

    id := params.ByName("id")
    errorMsg := ""
    if id == "" {
        errorMsg = "Missing id in the request URI"
        log.Errorf(errorMsg)
        utils.HandleError(writer, http.StatusBadRequest, errorMsg)
        return
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        utils.HandleError(writer, http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("Invalid request body: %v", err)) // unexpected end of JSON inpu
        return
    }
    req_payload := &TestTableDetails{}
    // parse input json message
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, req_payload)
    if err != nil {
        utils.HandleError(writer, http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("Invalid request body: %v", err))
        return
    }
}
```

My route is perfectly directing to the code as i have similar get API currently printing response in JSON form in response body.

And i try printing request in the log above, this is the logged value

**test log request.RequestURI is /test/1 request.Body {}, request.Method PUT**

Any help/approach is highly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure your curl command is "clean" i.e. doesn't have any rogue characters in and around the JSON body part?